# Which LINQ expression is faster

Tags: c#, .net, linq, performance, compiler-construction

**Hi All**

In following code

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public uint Age { get; set; }

    public Person(string name, uint age)
    {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var data = new List<Person>{ new Person("Bill Gates", 55), 
                                new Person("Steve Ballmer", 54), 
                                new Person("Steve Jobs", 55), 
                                new Person("Scott Gu", 35)};

    // 1st approach
    data.Where (x => x.Age > 40).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Age++);

    // 2nd approach
    data.ForEach(x => 
                    {
                        if (x.Age > 40)
                            x.Age++;
                    });

    data.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));    
}
```

in my understanding 2nd approach should be faster since it iterates through each item once and first approach is running 2 times:

1. Where clause
2. ForEach on subset of items from where clause.

However internally it might be that compiler translates 1st approach to the 2nd approach anyway and they will have the same performance.

Any suggestions or ideas?

I could do profiling like suggested, but I want to understand what is going on compiler level if those to lines of code are the same to the compiler, or compiler will treat it literally.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: profiling... do a measurement with StopWatch and see what is faster

Comment: Can you not just time it to see which is faster?

Comment: ps. technically the second method (ForEach on the list) is not Linq, since its a direct method on the List-class taking a delegate as parameter.

Comment: A man much smarter than me once said "you've already written it both ways, test it yourself and determine if there is a relevant, demonstrable difference."

Comment: If you create a `ForEach` extension method for `IEnumerable` then you can remove the `ToList` and they would be the same.

Comment: Consider using foreach instead of ForEach. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran the code and the second runs faster:

```
static void T3()
        {
            var data = new List<Person>{ new Person("Bill Gates", 55), 
                                new Person("Steve Ballmer", 54), 
                                new Person("Steve Jobs", 55), 
                                new Person("Scott Gu", 35)};

            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s1 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            s1.Start();
            // 1st approach
            data.Where(x => x.Age > 40).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Age++);
            s1.Stop();

            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s2 = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();

            s2.Start();
            // 2nd approach
            data.ForEach(x =>
            {
                if (x.Age > 40)
                    x.Age++;
            });
            s2.Stop();

            Console.Write("s1: " + s1.ElapsedTicks + " S2:" + s2.ElapsedTicks);
            data.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
        }
```

This is to be expected, since the second doesn't need to convert to a list and then run the foreach method.

Results:  **s1: 1192 S2:255**

Comment: you bothered to run this test, but not show us the result? :)

Answer (score 2):

You argue against `.Where()` without measurement.  The real difference between the two approaches is the `.ToList()`.

3rd approach:

```
foreach(Person x in data.Where(x => x.Age > 40))
{
  x.Age++; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Paste the code into LinqPad (www.linqpad.net) and time it. Or you can examine the generated IL code to see how the compiler handles it.

Comment: I can, but like I said I am more interested in how compiler see this two expressions.  Since they are the same, should compiler optimize and have it as second approach?

Comment: @Vlad - Paste it into LinqPad and examine the resulting IL code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the first one will be slow because of  `ToList()`.  Creating a new data structure has to be relatively slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in how the compiler treats these two expressions, why not compile each, then use the ildasm tool (bundled with Visual Studio) to look at the code generated?